# What is the simplest way to check if two numbers are close to being equal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Here's my code:

```
variable1=201
variable2=202
if variable1==variable2:
    print ("done")
```

I want my code to recognise that the numbers are close to being equal and print "done". I want the computer to print "done" if the difference between the two numbers is less than or equal to 5.

Comment: You find the difference, and then check whether that is less than or equal to five.  `abs(v1-v2) <= 5`.  `abs` is the built in absolute value function

Comment: I wonder if `-5 <= v1-v2 <= 5` is any easier to read.

Comment: Should you check absolute or relative difference?  Being within five isn't bad if the numbers are large; not so good if they're small.

Comment: You're going to have to define what "close" means for your application.  If an absolute difference makes sense for the range of likely values then use that.  For larger ranges, it might make sense to see if the ratio of two numbers is close to 1.  Other applications it might be useful to consider the squared difference... it all depends.

Answer (score 3):

You can either subtract them and evaluate their absolute value as Patrick suggests or you could utilize [`isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) from the `math` module with a similar effect, if you're using Python `>= 3.5`.

Though suggested, `isclose` is probably not the best if you're starting out since the tolerance arguments might confuse, so I'd go with `abs(variable1 - variable2) <= 5` if I were you.

Comment: Is there a way to use `isclose` in dataframes such that you retain the rows that are close in a certain column?

Answer (score 1):

Could use:

```
variable1 = 201
variable2 = 202
if variable1 - variable2 in range(-5,5):
    print('Done')
```